# Elements in HTML, XHTML?

Tags: html, xhtml

How many elements are there in html, xhtml?
I want to know what is the exact number of these elements?

Comment: Why do you need to know that? Different versions of the standard will have different numbers.

Comment: be more specific with your questions

Comment: @Robert be more specific? It might not be a legendary question but it's very specific.

Comment: @TooManyCooks - No, it's not specific. It really depends which version of HTML, or what browsers recognise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to the [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/) consortium about HTML 4.01, in there you will find the [appendix](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/index/elements.html) to the elements used in HTML.

92 Elements to be exact by my count....